# Html.Action link and Html.RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper, actionlink, routelink

Even If the url is same can i go to different action using Html.RouteLink and Action Link.Like when i click on news link i will go to news details.The url of this page is http://localhost:1390/en-US/latestnews/125.Now if i select the ddl of language in the site header in this pagei need to
go to the home page of the site.The ddl (on change) will take the same url but this time it needs to go to action in the sane controller.

Answer (score 0):

The URL will direct to the controller/action on the first routing entry that it matches regardless of how you generate it.  I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but I suspect that what you need to do is use javascript to direct to a **different** url, perhaps generated with `Html.RouteLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink` based on the value of the drop down list when it's selected.  If I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do, please clarify.